# texture a planet in blender 2.57

Tags: 3d, blender, texturing

Can you tell me how to unwrap a sphere, so it will go as a ractangle, because when I unwrap  a sphere projection, it goes to very wierd UV map. I have the textures, but I cant use them, because of the UV map blender exports. Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: note this really isn't a programming question, and doesn't really fit on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to apply spherical mapping, without the need for UV mapping, but it's useful to know how to mark seams and control UV mapping. Check out [this blendercooki tutorial](http://www.blendercookie.com/2011/01/21/intro_uvmapping/)

[image: blender cookie UVW Mapping tutorial preview]